# Geometric interpretation of how function lower bounds aid gradient descent

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-geometry, gradient-descent

Suppose we are given a smooth (i.e., gradients are Lipschitz) function $f(x)$ and we try to find its minima via a simple gradient descent approach. Smoothness tells us that at each point $x$, the function $f(x)$ is bounded above by a quadratic. Finding the point that minimizes this quadratic immediately leads to the gradient descent update rule. Thus, there is a clear geometric interpretation of what smoothness buys us. Convexity and strong-convexity tell us that the function $f(x)$ is globally bounded below by a linear, and quadratic function, respectively. Is there a clear geometric interpretation of why this helps us? In terms of simple algebraic manipulations, standard proofs of convergence inform us that smoothness+convexity imply $||x_k-x^*||$ is a decreasing function of $k$, where $k$ is the iteration number, and $x^*$ is an optimal point. Again, is there a geometric interpretation of why the functional lower bounds supplied by either convexity or strong-convexity lead to the above phenomenon? Why does a quadratic lower bound (strong convexity) lead to better convergence than a linear lower bound (convexity)?

I understand the algebra that explains the above points, but it would be great to get more intuition.

Comment: Stream of consciousness worked well for Joyce (well, sort of), but not too well for mathematical questions...

Comment: Knowing the curvature gives a better idea of where the $\min$ lies.

Comment: Yes, but could you perhaps elaborate how knowledge of the function curvature translates into moving closer to the optimal point $x^*$ in each iteration based on gradient descent? Smoothness only guarantees decrease in the function value, but on its own, says nothing about moving closer to $x^*$

Comment: Not exactly sure how to answer. Maybe consider the following: Take $f(x) = e^{-x}$. Gradient descent will produce a sequence $x_k \to \infty$ while $f(x_k) \to 0$.